# My kendo chart data not displaying properly on pageload

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I have a **kendo grid** and **kendo chart** in my application.I am using shared data-source for both graph and grid. My problem is on page-load grid displays all data but chart displays only some data.

my chart code:

```
$("#Chart").kendoStockChart({
    theme         : $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "metro",
    dataSource    : DataSource,
    autoBind      : false,
    legend        : {
        position: "right", visible: true
    },
    dateField     : "date",
    seriesDefaults: { type: "line" },
    series        : [
        {
            field: "value",
            name : "value"
        }
    ],
    valueAxis: [
        {
            max    : 5.0,
            min    : 0,
            labels : {
                format: "{0}"
            },
            tooltip: { visible: true, format: "{0}" }
        }
    ],
    navigator: {
        series: [
            { field: "item", type: "area"}
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to share in JSFiddle or JSBin some example showing what happens?

Comment: here is the fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/mga6f/74/ I tried this code.where i am wrong?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't run!

Comment: ya it's not working in fiddle but that code is working in my application.my requ is this way   http://jsfiddle.net/mga6f/72/

Comment: But in this last example works, correct? I might try to help you finding the problem in your code but I need to be able to reproduce it. If the code that you include in JSFiddle does not even run...

Comment: I am  trying to run this fiddle but URL not bind to grid and chart.here is the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mga6f/82/. in this fiddle i put my  code which is in my application,please check it once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to a newer version of Kendo UI v2012.3.1315.

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**EDIT**:
If you share a DataSource between two Kendo UI widgets you are sharing *every* option, this includes `pageSize`. So either you display all results in the `grid` or you display only those items in a page in the `chart`.

Instead of sharing, I recommend *sharing* the result (content) of the `DataSource`. I mean:

1. Define the `DataSource`, the `Grid` and the `Chart` as you are doing now.
2. Replace the value of `dataSource` in the `Grid` by `undefined`.
3. Add to the *shared* `DataSource` definition a `change` event that assigns the data to `Grid.dataSource`.

Something like this:

```
var sharedDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type     : "odata",
    transport: {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    schema   : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                OrderDate: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    },
    change   : function (e) {
        grid.dataSource.data(e.items);
    }
});
```

Check the code running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/

Comment: Thank you for your quick responding,but we are also using same version of kendo ui  in commercial product,but still graph is not displaying.

Comment: Do you mean that my fiddle doesn't work? It takes some time because of the file being transferred takes a long time but at the end, it displays.

Comment: your fiddle is working fine but here issue is while page load grid should display only 20 records that means it display the default page size and also in chart should display all the records data.Is it possible?

Comment: The reason for showing all is that in the DataSource does not include pageSize. Sharing a DataSource has this drawback. The alternative -avoiding two completely independent datasources- would be sharing the data -building a second DataSource that uses the data retrieved from the first-. See my **EDIT** in the answer above.

Comment: ya,it's working fine,but  Graph is not changing while filtering the grid or while changing paging

Comment: Correct, now they are two different DataSources. You should understand `paging` as a type of `filtering` where the condition is not related to value but to number of elements. Either it is a shared data source or it is not, there are no options for mixing. If what you need is to do not have such a long grid (initial content without paging) you might use grid height option that limits the number of records visible and you scroll down for showing the rest. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/2/

Comment: ya it's great idea for applying  height to the grid but while filter the data, if it having only 2 records also grid in same height (i.e remaining space is in white) is their any option to dynamically re-size the grid?

Comment: No (as far as I know). You can try programmatically but not sure if it will work as expected since KendoUI does some clever computations for determining grid sizes so playing with it you might break it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time

Comment: Hi onabai,                                                         yours code is working fine but i had an small issue  while filtering  the grid, chart is displaying the filtered data but only in  front(first) page of grid data but not remaining pages data.how to display the all pages filtered data in chart.?Is it possible?

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, you cannot! Last reviewed answer was not using paging. As soon as you use paging again, you will not see it. You have to choose between sharing the datasource and having to display every row in the grid **or** you have paging and then you have to use two datasources and when grid changes (for example, new filter condition) apply those same conditions to the chart datasource.

Comment: OK onabai..To change both grid and chart we need shared data source and grid with out paging is it correct.?but with the small data without paging its working fine but we are using large amount of data.But when the page is loading if the grid is showing all the data, my page getting strucked and after same time it gets killed in browser.what's the problem?

Comment: As it seems: the problem is that _large amount of data_. I don't know if it's a bug or just the browser runs out of memory with that _large amount of data_. I would say that there is little that you can do other than do not display a chart/grid with more than XYZ number of records. You can try limiting the number of records retrieved requesting a maximum or changing the server to do not return more than XYZ.

Comment: here problem is,service  data(json format) is in not our control ,it's provided by client,so how can  restrict the data flow by giving XYZ number of records?

Comment: Is the server able of doing `serverPaging`? See documentation [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#serverpaging-booleandefault). If so, you should use `take` for telling them how many records you want. If they are not, you should receive whatever they send and before using the data for the chart / grid, display a message saying that too many data and not populating the chart.